# I wrote a code to load a csv file directly from the web source into r markdown but I am running into some issues

Tags: r

The problems come back as unused arguments but I also get notified that no such file or directory found when I try to run it. I am sure the problem is in my code but I just cannot figure out where since I am extremely new to R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
```

```
consumer_good <- read_csv("http://web.stcloudstate.edu/mdernst/325/ConsumerGood.csv",›
                          Distribution = col_double(),
                          Market_Share = col_double(),
                          Price = col_double())
consumer_good
```

Answer (score 2):

To specify the column types you have to pass a named `list` to the `col_types` argument. Also, to use names different from the ones ion the data you have to specify the names via the `col_names` argument and in that case `skip` the first line containing the column names:

```r
library(readr)

read_csv("http://web.stcloudstate.edu/mdernst/325/ConsumerGood.csv",
  col_names = c("id", "Distribution", "Market_Share", "Price"),
  col_types = list(
    Distribution = col_double(),
    Market_Share = col_double(),
    Price = col_double()
  ),
  skip = 1
)
#> # A tibble: 108 × 4
#>       id Distribution Market_Share Price
#>    <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1        0.905         2.74  106.
#>  2     2        0.9           3.01  106.
#>  3     3        0.988         2.20  107.
#>  4     4        0.96          2.67  106.
#>  5     5        0.954         2.87  106.
#>  6     6        0.988         2.77  106.
#>  7     7        0.976         2.65  107.
#>  8     8        0.93          3.11  105.
#>  9     9        0.982         4.28  109.
#> 10    10        0.88          2.36  110.
#> # … with 98 more rows
```